# How to pass a RequestDelegate to a MiddleWare Constructor?

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm reading a chapter in Apress ASP.Net Core 6 and it has a lot of examples of middleware.

There is a pattern in middleware where you can have the middleware class act as terminal or non-terminal.

A private nullable `RequestDelegate` field is declared. Then one constructor takes a `RequestDelegate` and one constructor takes no parameters so the `RequestDelegate` field will be null.

If the `RequestDelgate` is not null, the middleware calls the next middleware in the pipeline. Otherwise the pipeline terminates.

Here is one example:

```
namespace Platform
{
    public class Capital
    {
        private RequestDelegate? next;

        public Capital() { }

        public Capital(RequestDelegate nextDelegate)
        {
            next = nextDelegate;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            string[] parts = context.Request.Path.ToString()
                .Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (parts.Length == 2 && parts[0] == "capital")
            {
                string? capital = null;
                string country = parts[1];

                switch (country.ToLower())
                {
                    case "uk":
                        capital = "London";
                        break;
                    case "france":
                        capital = "Paris";
                        break;
                    case "monoco":
                        context.Response.Redirect($"/population/{country}");
                        return;
                }

                if (capital != null)
                {
                    await context.Response
                        .WriteAsync($"{capital} is the capital of {country}");
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (next != null)
            {
                await next(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is the call in program.cs:

```
using Platform;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<Population>();
app.UseMiddleware<Capital>();

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Terminal Middleware Reached");
});

app.Run();
```

How would I pass a `RequestDelegate` in this call?

```
app.UseMiddleware<Capital>();
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more where do you pass RequestDelegate? Do you want to pass to your middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Could be done like this :

```
app.UseMiddleware<Capital>((context, next) =>
    {
        var capitalMiddleware = new Capital(next);
        return capitalMiddleware.Invoke(context);
    });
```